# Canadian student visa, fake documents for USA while minor

Tags: visa, canada, student-visa, refusal

In March 2019 my USA F4 (PR) visa was refused because my parents provided fake documents in 2002, which reflect in 2019 at the time of interview.
Visa officer had given refusal letter to my parents but not to me.

As of now I'm applying for Canadian student visa, will USA record effect my student application for Canada?

Is yes, how to overcome this problem?

Comment: I am going to migrate this question to Expats but you can only get a good answer if you add your nationality.

Comment: You will be asked on the forms to provide information and the details. It something that Canadian has an inherent responsibility to take into account. It happened a long time ago, so there is that. Have you been living the U.S. the whole time since?